# Timevis - make different boxes have colour dependent on name in different groups

Tags: r, plot, visualization, timeline

Hi So what i'd like to be able to do is make all the ranges which contain open appear say "red" and Staff meeting appear blue. Is it possible to do this, could only see documentation on changing the colour based off the group.
I know I can use style to change the text but that only changes the colour of the text inside the box and not the background shading of the box.

```
 library(timevis)
    # Data for groups example
    dataGroups <- data.frame(
      id = 1:11,
      content = c("Open", "Open",
                  "Open", "Open", "Half price entry",
                  "Staff meeting", "Open", "Adults only", "Open", "Hot tub closes",
                  "Siesta"),
      start = c("2016-05-01 07:30:00", "2016-05-01 14:00:00",
                "2016-05-01 06:00:00", "2016-05-01 14:00:00", "2016-05-01 08:00:00",
                "2016-05-01 08:00:00", "2016-05-01 08:30:00", "2016-05-01 14:00:00",
                "2016-05-01 16:00:00", "2016-05-01 19:30:00",
                "2016-05-01 12:00:00"),
      end   = c("2016-05-01 12:00:00", "2016-05-01 20:00:00",
                "2016-05-01 12:00:00", "2016-05-01 22:00:00", "2016-05-01 10:00:00",
                "2016-05-01 08:30:00", "2016-05-01 12:00:00", "2016-05-01 16:00:00",
                "2016-05-01 20:00:00", NA,
                "2016-05-01 14:00:00"),
      group = c(rep("lib", 2), rep("gym", 3), rep("pool", 5), NA),
      type = c(rep("range", 9), "point", "background")
    )

    groups <- data.frame(
      id = c("lib", "gym", "pool"),
      content = c("Library", "Gym", "Pool")
      )

    timevis(data = dataGroups, groups = groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
 tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".vis-item.blah { color: black; background-color: #1ac6ff; border-color: #1ac6ff; }"))
```

where .blah is an items className

Comment: Hi @Zuti, thanks for posting your findings! 
Could you please post a complete working example?
Where do you define  tags$head , and how do you link each style to a particular box?

Comment: @Ant, sorry for slow reply:  inside of your: tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("            
                    .vis-item.item1 { color: black; border-color: grey; }
)) 
You can create a vis-item, then you just need to give a particular item that  style, which I did by text:
        mutate(className =
                 ifelse(grepl("item1",content), 'item1',)) This works on the classname part handling the styling

Comment: hi @Zuti, could you please post a full solution. I promise to upvote if the code works, straight on execution.

Comment: Hi mate, this isn't close to me anymore as I haven't worked on it in 4 years but this is my github repo that involved my timevis work - perhaps that will have your answer? https://github.com/Brownsey/Brownsey_gantt/blob/master/Brownsey_gantt.R