# How to set background transparent in timevis content in r?

Tags: html, css, r

I am using `timevis` package from r to create a timeline.

I would like to change the `content` items **box** to transparent instead of blue background default. I have been able to change the font color to orange but not able to change background to transparent (code, image shown below).

[image]

**Code** I have used :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(timevis)

data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,

  # 'background-color: transparent` is not working
  content = c("<span style='color:#ff8c00 style='background-color: transparent;'>Prescription</span>",
              "<strong>Hospitalization</strong>",
              "BloodReport",
              "Aerobic Pus Report",
              "Anaerobic Pus Report",
              "<span style='color:#ff8c00;'>Prescription</span>",
              "<span style='color:#ff8c00;'>Prescription</span>",
              "MRI",
              "Cultre Report", 
              "<span style='color:#ff8c00;'>Prescription</span>"
              ),
  start = c("2020-11-18","2020-11-20","2020-11-20","2020-11-23","2020-11-25","2020-11-28","2020-12-12",
            "2020-12-14","2020-12-17","2020-12-25"),
  end = c(NA,NA,NA,NA, NA, NA, NA,NA,NA,NA)
)

timevis::timevis(data)
```

Also tried:

```
"<span style='color:#ff8c00; 'background-color: transparent;'>Prescription</span>"
```

I have referred below SO post for this:

[Is background-color:none valid CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739665/is-background-colornone-valid-css)

[Multiple "style" attributes in a "span" tag: what's supposed to happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867083/multiple-style-attributes-in-a-span-tag-whats-supposed-to-happen)

Comment: There can be a single style attribute. If not, only one will be used. Style rules are to be separated via **;**   . Also you have a  typo a closing quote before baçkground.

Comment: if you need just transparent with color at all, set background-color: #ffffff00;

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: I have tried these now:
1. `"<span style='color:#ff8c00';style='background-color: transparent'>Prescription</span>"` (2). `"<span style='color:#ff8c00'; 'background-color: transparent'>Prescription</span>"` (3). `"<span style='color:#ff8c00; background-color: transparent'>Prescription</span>"` (4). `"<span style='color:#ff8c00 style = background-color: transparent'>Prescription</span>"`. None of these worked. Could you please help me with the correct line of code for this `span`.

Comment: @aktoriukas, I am looking to make them `colored font without any background or white background`. Not sure how to combine them together in one `span`. Could you please help me with the single line of code that includes both of these properties ?

Comment: only one style attribute !! , `<span style="color:black;background:white" >span</span>` :)

Comment: Thanks @G-Cyrillus, this helped and have set the **background of text** white but not of the entire **box**. Is there a way to change the **background color** of the **box* to white which contains this text (pls refer to the image in the post)?

Comment: you should be able to do so since you now understood how to write inline style ;)

Comment: Thanks @G-Cyrillus, I was not sure how to access **box items**. But I think I can get it done using this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885083/timevis-make-different-boxes-have-colour-dependent-on-name-in-different-groups.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work with timevis. All HTML attributes are removed in the final HTML code.. No matter how you write it.. with timevis 2.1 at least